# Xcode auto layout issue when open app

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints

i set all constraints there is no probmem. But when i re-open the project all widths and heights values changes to 1000. There is only one view has problem. I deleted it then created again but still has same problem. How can i solve this?

[image: solved picture]

[image: problem picture]

Comment: try deleting the storyboard and starting again

Comment: there are 17 views, i cant delete all of them :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in Xcode 8.

Related Question: [xcode-8-storyboard-warnings-for-navigation-bar-width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492765/xcode-8-storyboard-warnings-for-navigation-bar-width)

A possible solution presented in that related question is to change the Simulated Metrics size from **Fixed** to **Freeform**.

Also, here some open threads about common problems:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62929
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63108
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63144
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/61797
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63029
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63068
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63067
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63067
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62821
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62882
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62321